Manually complete hydration of ssr components in a single SPA instance
In a single SPA instance (such as vue or react), split a single large component and use SSR to return an HTML string. How to complete the hydration in this SPA instance? I noticed that both vue and react have corresponding APIs, but they seem to need to recreate the SSRAPP instance. I want to know if there is a way to activate the component in the existing instance

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It doesn't make sense to ask a question in general, focus on a single framework. A vague description not constructive enough, you need to show what you try and the results. "recreate the SSRAPP instance" - what does this mean?
